# Does Envers function not work if I use JPQL?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers, but if I use JQPL grammar, can't I detect deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Envers is build on the entity life cycle events and those do not get triggered when you execute modifying queries.

So yes, you are correct, things like `delete myentity where something = somethingelse` don't get tracked by envers.